# Why and when to use RPi.GPIO vs BCM2835

Tags: gpio

I have only worked with the RPi.GPIO library, thought it was the only way to interface with the GPIO pins, then I came across [this library](https://github.com/ToninoTarsi/swpi/blob/master/TX23/bcm2835.c). If you go up a folder you can see the other files its associated with on that project.

Does the BCM library serve the same purpose as the RPi, and what is the benefit of using one over the other?

Answer (score 2):

There are dozens of GPIO libraries for the Pi allowing access from multiple programming languages.

Which is best would likely depend on what it was being used for as they all have their pluses and minuses.

https://elinux.org/RPi_GPIO_Code_Samples

Comment: Its strange that this page states for the case of "bcm2835 library" that "This must be done as root". However later in the Perl section they say that SPI access requires root but GPIO can be accessed by any user.

Comment: The GPIO part of memory can be accessed via `/dev/gpiomem` without needing root privileges if the user is a member of group `gpio`.  That was an extension added to Raspbian by raspberrypi.org as accessing the GPIO is a very common requirement.  Before this addition lots of Python programs had to be run as root which was a bad thing to do.  The bcm2835 library accesses the SPI hardware memory directly so needs to use `/dev/mem` which does require root access.  Other libraries may use the Linux SPI driver which does not require root privileges, just that the user be a member of group `spi`.

Comment: OK, understood so this C library that the OP referred to does actually require root access, because in `bcm2835_init()` it specifically opens `/dev/mem` to access all registers and not `/dev/gpiomem`  in source file `bcm2835.c`. So you were correct when you stated that "The Pi does not require root privileges to access the GPIO", but in my answer I was specifically talking about access via `/dev/mem`. I see a lot of confusion about what we were talking about in this discussion, but I feel that I learned a lot of useful info from you eventually.

Answer (score 1):

If you are primarily a Python programmer then of course the Python library makes sense, but I suspect it is pretty slow, for example to continuously toggle an output pin, relative to how fast this could be done with native code on the ARM chip, especially running single threaded.

Most conventional interfacing to the GPIOs is done by reading and writing values to their file mapping at `/sys/class/gpio`. This is the "normal" Linux way of interacting with devices, by representing them as objects in the file system that can be opened, read, written, and closed, for example by using POSIX functions. This has the advantage of making a unified interface for everyone using the OS, and need not require root access. I presume that Python and other libraries use this method under the hood. The downside is that there is a lot of code overhead to do a simple thing like setting a GPIO pin high.

The library that you reference bypasses all this by directly reading and writing to the hardware GPIO registers that control the pin functions. To do this within Linux requires first that some initialization code opens `/dev/mem` and gets pointers to the internal memory for the BCM 2835 device registers. This can only be done by root, so it's not so convenient on a multiuser machine.

The advantage however is that changes to pin state require just a line or two of C code and so access is very fast. But note that Linux is not a real time operating system and so there is no guarantee that the code won't get constantly interrupted because of the normal multitasking process. So you still won't be able to, for example output a high frequency square wave by programmatically writing 1s and 0s without considerable timing jitter, because the CPU might be required to frequently go off and spend a few milliseconds doing some other task. The various hardware timer modules should instead be used for producing accurately timed waveforms.

Another potential down side is that using direct access bypasses the OS. This means that the states of the pins are not being correctly reflected in the file system representation, and this could potentially screw with any other processes that try to access devices the conventional way.

So the advantage of the low level C library is speed, but it requires root privilege and makes changes that the OS is blind to, potentially causing problems with other code that tries to access the ports.

Comment: The Pi does not require root privileges to access the GPIO.  There are plenty of programs which output jitter free square waves.

Comment: Both of your comments misread what I wrote. Firstly I didnt say you in general need root privileges to access GPIO. You *only* need root privileges to access the registers directly bypassing the OS, via this memory mapper C code that the OP quoted. Normal user access can be done using the file system representation, which is what most people use. Secondly while there may be programs outputting jitter free square waves, they are not doing it by writing 1 and 0 to ports, but instead by configuring the BCM hardware timers to generate waveforms. There's a big difference.

Comment: I revised my answer to make it clearer.

Comment: You need root privileges to access the sysfs interface just as much as you need root privileges to access GPIO memory.

Comment: You don't have to be root on the RPI because there is gpio group which allows the default pi user access to sysfs GPIO. This is done by asking the kernel to export the GPIOs you need, either with the `gpio export` command or (if you want gpio11) by `echo 11 > /sys/class/gpio/export` which creates a directory `/sys/class/gpio/gpio11` containing a bunch of control files that can be accessed in the usual way. E.g. `echo out > /sys/class/gpio/gpio11/direction` or `echo 0 > /sys/class/gpio/gpio11/value`, or `cat /sys/class/gpio/gpo11/value`. Works just fine without sudo for me.

Comment: ...and the same mechanism allows rootless access to the GPIO via memory without the limitations or overhead of sysfs.

Comment: Your comments seem very confusing to me, Firstly you said you don't need root privileges to access the GPIO, and then you said you do need root privileges to access the sysfs interface and to access GPIO memory, and now you are suggesting again that you agree with what I wrote above, and adding that one can access GPIO memory without being root. Are you intending to say that both direct and sysfs methods are available without root privileges if the user is a member of the gpio group? I may be wrong but I feel skeptical about mapping device registers into user space without being root from C.

Comment: You need root privileges just as much is what I said.  You don't need root privileges for either access.

Comment: OK Sorry I was confused by the phrasing of your comments. It's clear that I don't know enough about the finer detail of security groups on Linux, but I can believe you if you're saying that the user/group access protection is consistent between memory mapping registers in code and using sysfs, given that they're targeting the same resources.